# Как задать в gdb пути к библиотекам для core dump?

Tags: gdb, linux

Есть coredump от упавшей программы, запущенной на другой машине. Есть библиотеки, на которые coredump ссылается. Но путь к библиотекам при запуске софтины на другой машине отличается от пути к библиотекам на машине, где запускается gdb.

Посему вопрос: как в gdb задать путь к этим библиотекам?

Answer (score 2):

мало того, что пути отличаются, так, скрее всего, отличаются и сами библиотеки.

вам нужно получить ровно те же самые файлы, что использовались на «другой» машине. путь к иерархии скопированных библиотек можно указать с помощью:

```
set sysroot путь
```

или (это синоним):

```
set solib-absolute-prefix путь
```

подробности смотрите в `info gdb` или [онлайн](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Files.html#index-set-sysroot-1186).